# Does my Wireless USB Adapter support monitor mode?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, usb

I have a TL-WN721N Wireless USB Adapter and it has Atheros AR9271 2.0.0.32 driver version. Is it possible to send packets and set the mode to monitor with this adapter chipset? I read on a post and it said this:

> Atheros AR9271: The Alfa AWUS036NHA is my favorite long-range network
>   adapter and the standard by which I judge other long-range adapters.
>   It's stable, fast, and a well-supported b/g/n wireless network
>   adapter. There's also the TP-Link TL-WN722N, a favorite for newbies
>   and experienced hackers alike. It's a compact b/g/n adapter that has
>   one of the cheapest prices but boasts surprisingly impressive
>   performance. That being said, only v1 will work with Kali Linux since
>   v2 uses a different chipset.

I don't know if he referred to the driver version or chipset version. I can't find the information about the version of my chipset but the driver Atheros AR9271 has the version 2.0.0.32.

Also when I run `iwconfig wifi0 mode monitor` it shows this error message:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wifi0 ; Invalid argument.
```

And when I run `sudo airmon-ng start wifi0` it just gives me this and doesn't list any networks:

```
PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
```

I am using a Kali Linux subsystem on my Windows 10 OS. Maybe that can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. You've hit the nail on the head: Windows ***Subsystem***  for Linux:  It's good to muck around in `bash` and use most of the GNU tools, but when you need deeper access into the system, it will not provide that functionality [as per the Micro$oft WSL about section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)

   > The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run GNU/Linux environment -- including **most** command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a virtual machine.

   (Emphasis mine)

   *because the WSL doesn't even contain a Linux kernel!*
2. As per the Kali Linux [Docs section](https://docs.kali.org/):

   > 1. Getting Started(4)
   > 2. Kali Linux Live(3)
   > 3. Installing Kali Linux(9)

   Kali is meant to be run live (Chapter 2) *before you even try the next chapter* on installing it on bare metal or (heaven forbid) dual booting it with Windows.

<sub>**Note:** No, a Kali VM is not a good substitute for booting it live from a USB Stick: You'll be running into the same kind of issues as running under WSL.</sub>

Comment: As per Fabby's answer: **WSL is not Linux** - do not even think of doing low-level operations there. Nevertheless, I advise seeing what hw supports monitor mode *before* buying it. There are also databases out there for that, no need for asking here for each specific chipset.